# Prove equivalence relation (solution verification)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

I have tried to solve these exercises that require proving if a certain relation is an equivalence relation, but I have no solutions, are my solutions right?

*Note: I'll use $\rho$ to refer to the relation.*

1. $$ x \rho y \iff x^2=y^2 \\ \textbf{resolution:} \\  \text{reflexive:}  \ x^2= x^2 \ (true) \\ \text{symmetric:} \ x^2=y^2 \iff y^2=x^2 (true) \\ \text{transitive:} \ x^2=y^2, y^2 = z^2 \implies z^2 = x^2 (true)$$
   and so is an equivalence relation.
2. $$ x \rho y \iff x-y\in \mathbb{Z} \\ \textbf{resolution:} \\ \text{reflexive:}  \ x-x= 0 \in \mathbb{Z} \ (true) \\ \text{symmetric:} \ x-y \iff y-x \in \mathbb{Z}  \ (true) \\ \text{transitive:} \ x-y \in \mathbb{Z}, y-z \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x-z \in \mathbb{Z} (true)  \text{ because} \ x-y+y-z \in \mathbb{Z}$$
   and so is an equivalence relation.
3. $$ (x,y) \rho (z,t) \iff x+y = z+t \\ \textbf{resolution:} \\ \text{reflexive:}  \ x+y = y+x \ (true) \\ \text{symmetric:} \ x+y = z+t \implies z+t = x+y  \ (true) \\ \text{transitive:} \ x+y = z+t, z+t = a+b \implies x+y = a+b \ (true)  \text{ because} \ a+b = z+t \ $$
   and so is an equivalence relation.
4. $$ A=\{f: \mathbb{R \to R}\}\\ f \rho g \iff f(1) = g(1) \\ \textbf{resolution:} \\ \text{reflexive:}  \ f(1) = f(1) \ (true) \\ \text{symmetric:} \ f(1) = g(1) \implies g(1) = f(1)  \ (true) \\ \text{transitive:} \ f(1) = g(1), g(1) = h(1) \implies f(1)=h(1) \ (true) \text{ because } h(1) = g(1)$$
   and so is an equivalence relations.

Comment: Looks good to me. There's a nice general result that for any function $f : A \to B$, the relation $a \rho b \iff f(a) = f(b)$ is always an equivalence relation. This lets you solve 1, 3, and 4 immediately. If you've seen any abstract algebra, 2 is the special case of a very general result (but would be too difficult to explain it in a comment).

Comment: @MarkSaving thanks for the advice!